# build Raspberry with new config (Pi2)

Tags: cobalt

We want to build cobalt with arm toolchain for arm chip.

First, we reference this link "[How to build for Raspberry Pi2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603478/how-to-build-for-raspberry-pi2)"

Then, we set `RASPI_HOME="./"`,create a folder `"./sysroot"`, replace `"raspi-1_"` with `"raspi-2_"` in 1gyp_configuration.gypi1 and setup our arm toolchain in `gyp_configuration.py`.

but we got some **error** message as below,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gyp_cobalt", line 271, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "./gyp_cobalt", line 261, in main
    gyp_return = gyp_runner.BuildConfig(config_name)
  File "./gyp_cobalt", line 175, in BuildConfig
    return gyp.main(args)
  File "/cobalt/cobalt-git/src/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 541, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "/cobalt/cobalt-git/src/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 526, in gyp_main
    generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
  File "/cobalt/cobalt-git/src/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/ninja.py", line 2277, in GenerateOutput
    user_config)
  File "/cobalt/cobalt-git/src/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/ninja.py", line 2223, in GenerateOutputForConfig
    spec, config_name, generator_flags)
  File "/cobalt/cobalt-git/src/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/ninja.py", line 405, in WriteSpec
    config = spec['configurations'][config_name]
KeyError: 'raspi-2_debug'
```

did we have to set other configuration correctly?

Comment: improved grammar and formatting

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that gyp_configuration.py and gyp_configuration.gypi contain the new platform configuration name ('raspi-2').

Comment: thanks, it work. it still have other problem.       ../../third_party/mozjs/js/src/assembler/wtf/Platform.h:354:6: error: #error "Not supported ARM architecture"
 #    error "Not supported ARM architecture".     did we lost some configuration ?

Comment: @user7160805 - It looks like it is trying to autodetect which ARM instruction set to use for JIT. You may have to set `-mcpu=cortex-a7` in your compiler flags so that `__ARM_ARCH_7A__` is defined by the compiler. This isn't something I've personally done before, so I don't know if that is sufficient, or if there further modifications required to make this work.